# Is it possible to store select query as variable ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to compare different dataframes, but they have some irrelevant columns for comparing.

I'm using select to filter out some columns, which I don't need. `.select(col("b.start"), col("b.end")`

But imagine, this select is much bigger. I'm using it in many places.

It's duplicating the code and on top of that it reduce readability.

Can I store it to some variable so I can change this

```
val remaining = difference_df.except(source_df.select(col("b.start"), col("b.end")))
```

into something like this

```
val my_select = ... .select(col("b.start"), col("b.end"))
val remaining = difference_df.except(source1_df.select(my_select))

val remaining = difference_df.except(source2_df.select(my_select))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
val cols = List(col("b.start"), col("b.end"))
```

or

```
val cols = List($"b.start", $"b.end")
```

and in you select you do

```
.select(cols: _*)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
val colNames = Seq("col1", "col2" ...)
val exclude = source_df.select(colNames.map(x => col(x)): _*)
val remaining = difference_df.except(exclude)
```